# How to manage cross-sells most effectively?

Tags: cross-sells

I posted a question about adding a step in the regular Magento checkout (not one-step checkout) and I understand now that it is pretty much not possible. I am wondering now if there is a way to always show the same 6 cross-sell products? With the layout I have - it doesn't show them all...Maybe an extension or something? I need to increase my sales by offering additional items (balloons etc.)

EDIT after I've done all the steps posted below: I have created all these folders and files in the specified directories. I have also renamed everything that says: "mycompany" to "AccessShop" (the name of my theme) - is that correct? I uploaded all the files to the paths specified above but I don't see this extra page with cross-sell items anywhere on the front or back-end? Where shall I look for this?

Comment: you need to write a custom module

Comment: somebody please help...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply may be it's help others

You need to implement your own module to do so

app/code/local/MyCompany/Checkout/Block/Cart in Crosssell.php

```
class MyCompany_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell extends  Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{

//     /**
//      * Items quantity will be capped to this value
//      *
//      * @var int
//      */
//     protected $_maxItemCount = 100;

//     /**
//      * Get crosssell items
//      *
//      * @return array
//      */

public function getItemCount()
{
     return count($this->getItems());
}

public function getItems()
{
    $items = $this->getData(\'items\');
    if (is_null($items)) {
    $items = array();
    $ninProductIds = $this->_getCartProductIds();
    if ($ninProductIds) {
        $lastAdded = (int) $this->_getLastAddedProductId();
        if ($lastAdded) {
            $collection = $this->_getCollection()
                ->addProductFilter($lastAdded);
            if (!empty($ninProductIds)) {
                $collection->addExcludeProductFilter($ninProductIds);
            }
            $collection->setPositionOrder()->load();

            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $ninProductIds[] = $item->getId();
                $items[] = $item;
            }
        }

        if (count($items) < 100) {
            $filterProductIds = array_merge($this->_getCartProductIds(), $this->_getCartProductIdsRel());
            $collection = $this->_getCollection()
                ->addProductFilter($filterProductIds)
                ->addExcludeProductFilter($ninProductIds)
                ->setPageSize(100-count($items))
                ->setGroupBy()
                ->setPositionOrder()
                ->load();
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $items[] = $item;
            }
        }

    }

    $this->setData(\'items\', $items);
   }
   return $items;
  }
 }
```

app/code/local/MyCompany/Checkout/etc in config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<MyCompany_Checkout>
    <version>1.0</version>
</MyCompany_Checkout>
</modules>
<global>
<blocks>
    <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <cart_crosssell>MyCompany_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell</cart_crosssell>
            </rewrite>
    </checkout>
    <mycompany_checkout>
        <class>MyCompany_Checkout_Block</class>
    </mycompany_checkout>
</blocks>
</global>
```

app/etc/modules in MyCompany_Checkout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<MyCompany_Checkout>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
</MyCompany_Checkout>
</modules>
```

app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/ in checkout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<reference name="content">
<block type="mycompany_checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

EDIT : To make the value selectable in the backend, you'll want to create:

app/code/local/MyCompany/Checkout/etc in system.xml:

```
<config>
<tabs>
<mycompany_tab translate="label" module="mycompany">
    <label>MyCompany X-Sell Settings</label>
    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
</mycompany_tab>
</tabs>
<sections>
 <mycompany_section translate="label" module="mycompany">
    <label>Max QTY For Upsell Block</label>
    <tab>mycompany_tab</tab>
    <frontend_type>How many</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>      
    <groups>
        <mycompany_group translate="label">
            <label>Settings</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <fields>
                <mycompany_field>
                    <label>Maximum QTY To Display</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <comment>This is the maximum number of upsell products to display</comment>                    
                </mycompany_field>
            </fields>                      
        </mycompany_group>
    </groups>              
</mycompany_section>
</sections>
```

Add this to your existing app/code/local/MyCompany/Checkout/etc/ in config.xml:

```
....
<adminhtml>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <mycompany_section>
                                    <title>MyCompany - All</title>
                                </mycompany_section>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</adminhtml>
```

And finally, you'd want to replace app/code/local/MyCompany/Checkout/Block/Cart in Crossell.php:

```
 protected $_maxItemCount = 100;

 With

 protected $_maxItemCount = Mage::getStoreConfig('mycompany_section/mycompany_group/mycompany_field');
```

If you'd like to know why the config section works like it works, the best article for reference in my opinion is:

Alan Storm | [Custom Magento System Configuration](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration)

Good luck!

Comment: Hello and thank you for helping - let me please ask you this - are these 7 modifications suppose to replace those respective files altogether or just some content within the file? I am having trouble even locating the correct path - for example the first one - app/code/local/MyCompany/Checkout/Block/Cart in Crosssell.php --) I have app/code/local and in there "AccessShop" and "Mage" - if I go into AccessShop - there is no "CHECKOUT" directory just "ThemeOptions" and in "Mage" - I have the "Sales" folder only...

Comment: in the 2nd one - I find the confix.xml file in app/code/local/AccessShop/ThemeOptions/etc/ --> is that correct? and there is some content in that file - what do I need to do with that?

Comment: in "app/etc/modules/" there is nothing even remotely similar to a file named "MyCompany_Checkout.xml" - do I create this one?

Comment: this app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/ I don't have either....I have: "/public_html/app/design/frontend/accessshop/default/layout" but no checkout.xml file there - do I create one?

Comment: I have the "system.xml" file in /public_html/app/code/local/AccessShop/ThemeOptions/etc   but again - I have something in that file already...

Comment: the 6th change - I have the "config.xml" file here:  /public_html/app/code/local/AccessShop/ThemeOptions/etc

Comment: the last one - I can't find at all: app/code/local/MyCompany/Checkout/Block/Cart in Crossell.php does not exist on my Magento...

Comment: @Allysin That is the page you have to create. It should be in your custom module

Comment: by "custom module" you mean my custom theme?

Comment: I have created all these folders and files in the specified directories. I have also renamed everything that says: "mycompany" to "AccessShop" (the name of my theme) - is that correct? I uploaded all the files to the paths specified above but I don't see this extra page with cross-sell items anywhere on the front or back-end? Where shall I look for this?